# Stripe/React/Firebase: Value should be a PaymentIntent client secret. You specified: a SetupIntent client secret

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying to sign a customer up to a subscription product that has a 7 day free trial.

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
email,
name,
payment_method: paymentMethod,
invoice_settings: { default_payment_method: paymentMethod },
});


const params = {
customer: customer.id,
items: [{ price: "price_1N1TKrGxUje7SlyIeNldQvLT" }],
payment_settings: {
                  payment_method_options: {
                    card: {
                      request_three_d_secure: "any",
                    },
                  },
                  payment_method_types: ["card"],
                  save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription",
                },
                trial_period_days: 7,
                expand: ["pending_setup_intent"],
            }

            if (promo) params.promotion_code = promo;
            if (countrycode) params.currency = countrycode;

            // Create a subscription
            const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create(params);
            
              // Send back the client secret for payment
            response.json({
              message: "Subscription successfully initiated",
              clientSecret: subscription.pending_setup_intent.client_secret,
              subID:subscription.id,
            });
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            response.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
          }
```

They appear to go into Stripe all OK with payment being marked to happen in 7 days, but I get the following console error:

```
IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a PaymentIntent client secret. You specified: a SetupIntent client secret.
```

In the front end I am using:

```
const confirmPayment = await stripe?.confirmCardPayment(
response.clientSecret
);
```

How or where do I swap over the intent secret from SetupIntent to PaymentIntent?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `stripe?.confirmCardPayment` you should used instead `stripe?.confirmCardSetup`[[0](https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_card_setup)].

On an unrelated topic, I noticed you are passing a "default"
`paymentMethod` to the customer with this code

```js
payment_method: paymentMethod,
invoice_settings: { default_payment_method: paymentMethod },
```

if you're already collecting the PaymentMethod before creating the customer/subscription you don't need to recollect it after creating the subscription. The `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` on the customer is the Payment Method used to pay all subscription/one-off invoices if no other PaymentMethod is specified.

Comment: awesome thanks for that. Which payment_method should I remove?

Comment: I was just asking to see where does the `paymentMethod` you're passing to the create Customer is coming from.

Comment: from - const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
              email,
              name,
              payment_method: paymentMethod,
              invoice_settings: { default_payment_method: paymentMethod },
            });

Comment: you are passing a variable called paymentMethod to the `stripe.customers.create` function. from where do you get this variable?

Comment: From the frontend - const paymentMethod = await stripe?.createPaymentMethod({
        type: "card",
        card: elements?.getElement(CardElement),
        billing_details: {
          name,
          email,
        },
      });

Comment: also am getting errors on this form now - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76361502/stripe-missing-value-for-stripe-confirmcardsetup-intent-secret-value-should-be/

Comment: you're integration isn't optimal. you're collecting the Payment Method (PM) and then you're creating the subscription and use the `pending_setup_intent.client_secret` to collect another PM. I think you need to choose between either pre-collecting the PM or create the subscription, collect the PM and then update the customer and set `invoice_settings.d_p_m` with the PM created by for the subscription.