# Stripe: Missing value for stripe.confirmCardSetup intent secret: value should be a client_secret string

Tags: stripe-payments

Trying to process a payment on a subscription that has a free trial - the details seem to go into Stripe, but none of my processing if not an error is working.

I get the error of:

```
Missing value for stripe.confirmCardSetup intent secret: value should be a client_secret string
```

Part of my front end -

```
const response = await fetch("cloudfunctions.net/XXXX", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          paymentMethod: paymentMethod?.paymentMethod?.id,
          name,
          lname,
          email,
          promo,
          countrycode,
          priceId
        }),
      }).then((res) => res.json());
      
      const confirmPayment = await stripe?.confirmCardSetup(
        response.clientSecret
      );

      if (confirmPayment?.error) {
        console.log(confirmPayment.error.message);
      } else {
        console.log('SUBSCRIBED!');
      }
```

My functions:

```
const { name, email, promo, countrycode, paymentMethod } = request.body;
            // Create a customer
            const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
              email,
              name,
              payment_method: paymentMethod,
              invoice_settings: { default_payment_method: paymentMethod },
            });

            const params = {
              customer: customer.id,
                items: [{ price: "price_1N1TKrGxUje7SlyIeNldQvLT" }],
                payment_settings: {
                  payment_method_options: {
                    card: {
                      request_three_d_secure: "automatic",
                    },
                  },
                  payment_method_types: ["card"],
                  save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription",
                },
                trial_period_days: 7,
                expand: ["pending_setup_intent"],
            }

            if (promo) params.promotion_code = promo;
            if (countrycode) params.currency = countrycode;

            const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create(params);
            
            response.json({
              message: "Subscription successfully initiated",
              clientSecret: subscription.pending_setup_intent.client_secret,
              subID:subscription.id,
            });
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            response.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
          }
```

Any ideas why that error message in the console would be showing?

Comment: have you tried logging `response.clientSecret` to check what is the value before calling `confirmCardSetup`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the clientSecret that you've passed to stripe?.confirmCardSetup() is not a proper value.

Firstly, you need to verify that the "cloudfunctions.net/XXXX" API creates and returns a [SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/object?lang=node) object (pending_setup_intent object) and make sure that your error handling function throws when your "stripe.subscriptions.create" API call fails.

Secondly, on your frontend, you may try to console log the client secret before passing it to your stripe?.confirmCardSetup(). See if it matches the value format from "stripe.subscriptions.create" response.

Comment: I get an error of "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'client_secret')" in my firebase logs for the function

Comment: So that means your subscription.pending_setup_intent is null. You might check again your function, starting from this line of code: 
            const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create(params);

Comment: Correct - but why this is null - I don't understand - it all appears to go into Stripe correctly....